# Doctrine, erro ao gerar proxy

Tags: php, doctrine-2, slim

Gostaria de uma ajuda, estou recebendo esse erro de vez em quando, já pesquisei bastante, mas nada que me ajude a resolver.
Como disse esse erro não é retornado sempre. 
Nessa aplicação estou usando slim 3 e doctrine.

> Warning:  rename(arq.php.588005700baeb7.17642031,arq.php): Acesso
>   negado. (code: 5) in
>   **\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator.php**
>   on line 306

Comment: Bom dia, nem sei se está precisando ainda, mas poderia enviar as configurações do Doctrine? Você está usando o método `setAutoGenerateProxyClasses()`?